# Youtube no Flash fallback of Android WebView

Tags: android, flash, android-emulator, youtube

I am displaying an HTML page with a YouTube video embedded like this:

```
<embed width="425" height="344" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Rv_wg6BfRX8%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-    flash"></embed>
```

When I run the Activity with the WebView on a 1.6 Emulator, it seems to somehow recognize that Flash is not available and show a thumbnail instead with a clickable play-button which leads to the following uri:

```
vnd.youtube:Rv_wg6BfRX8
```

Unfortunately, this is not the behaviour of 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 emulators. They just show a small Flash icon and nothing happens if you click it.

Any idea how I can force that fallback mechanism on the other emulators as well?

By the way, YouTube embedding is of course working when there is flash installed.

Here are two screenshots, that should clarify the problem!

[image: 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 Emulator]

[image: 1.6 Emulator]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the tag under your Applications Manifest XML

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

After that Load up your application and Flash will be enabled in your WebView!

Comment: sorry, no change.
also, this seems to be an attribute that is only available from Android 3.0+. Also my problem is not that Flash isn't working when it is installed on the device, it is about the fallback mechanism when flash is not installed.